# How to give IAM Users admin access to EC2's based on tags?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, permissions, amazon-iam

I'm trying to give IAM users Full api/console access to an EC2 with the tag (key/value) UserName/[their IAM username].

I've tried the policy below which works for some stuff but not others and I can't figure out why it's not working for everything.

- user CAN start and stop an instance with a UserName tag set to their IAM username (they cannot do this without the below policy)
- user can NOT change instance type on an instance with their UserName tag (which seems to be a ec2:* action)
- user can NOT change termination protection on an instance with their UserName tag

**My IAM Policy**

- in addition to this policy, these users also have full read access with the pre-defined AWS policy `ReadOnlyAccess`.

  ```
  {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
          {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": "ec2:*",
              "Resource": "*",
              "Condition": {
                  "StringEquals": {
                      "ec2:ResourceTag/UserName": "${aws:username}"
                  }
              }
          },
          {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": "ec2:Describe*",
              "Resource": "*"
          }
      ]
  }
  ```

I combined pieces from a number of AWS articles to create this policy:
- https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-ec2-resource-tags/
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policies-ec2-console.html

Comment: Instance type modification and changing termination protection use `ModifyInstanceAttribute` API. This API does not support Resource-Level Permissions (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ec2-api-permissions.html#ec2-api-unsupported-resource-permissions).

Comment: @KrishnaKumarR - is there a better way to manage this type of user permission then? Could I get my desired behavior by attaching roles to the EC2 instances?

Comment: I believe this is the best way without writing any code.